# How to restore multiple neural network models in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, save, restore

I am designing a ensemble neural network with 3 simple feed-forward NNs. And now I am facing an issue of restoring these 3 neural networks for testing purpose. By now, 3 NN models are created and saved by the `saver` function.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()    
saver.save(sess, save_path=get_save_path(i), global_step=1000)
```

I had successfully saved them into ".checkpoint", ".meta", ".index", and ".data files as shown below.

[image]

I tried to restored them by using this coding:

```
 saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(get_save_path(i) + '-1000.meta')
 saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(save_dir))
```

But it only restore the third NN which is `network2` for testing. It has affected my result as the algorithm only takes 1 model (`network2`) and assumes all three NNs model are the same in ensemble function.

FYI:

My ideal ensemble function:

```
ensemble = (network0 + network1 + network2) / 3
```

Real outcome:

```
ensemble = (network2 + network2 + network2) / 3
```

How can I make TF to restore all 3 NN models together?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix things up. But let me first answer the question:

You will need to create the model multiple times under different scopes. Then it should be possible to average those variables.

Let's say you create 3 networks by

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# save 3 version
for i in range(3):
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    a = tf.get_variable('test', [1])

    assign_op = a.assign([i])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(assign_op)
        print a.name, sess.run(a)

        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        saver.save(sess, './model/version_%i' % i)
```

Here each network has the same graph structure and only contains a single parameter/weight name 'test'.

Then you will need to create the *same* graph multiple times, but under *different* variable_scopes, like

```py
# load all versions in different scopes
tf.reset_default_graph()

a_collection = []

for i in range(3):
    # use different var-scopes
    with tf.variable_scope('scope_%0i' % i):
        # create same network
        a = tf.get_variable('test', [1])
        a_collection.append(a)
```

Now, each restorer needs to know which scope or variable-name-mapping should be used. This can be done by

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print zip(sess.run(a_collection), [n.name for n in a_collection])

    for i in range(3):
        loader = tf.train.Saver({"test": a_collection[i]})
        loader = loader.restore(sess, './model/version_%i' % i)

    print sess.run(a_collection)
```

Which will give you

```
 [array([0.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32), array([2.], dtype=float32)]
```

as expected. Now you can do whatever you want with your model.

But this is **not** how ensemble predictions work! In ensemble-models you usually average the predictions **only**. SO you might run your script multiple times with the different models and then average afterwards the predictions.

If you really want to average the weights of your model, consider dumping the weights as a python-dict by using numpy.

Comment: I found this error in my code: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'assign'`

Comment: `a = tf.get_variable()` is a TensorFow object. Do not mix it up with numpy-arys.